# Qt executable error- dll library

Tags: c++, qt, pthreads, qt-creator, qmake

A Qt application which runs perfectly when executed from QtCreator, doesn't wont to run when I try to execute it from debug folder (without QtCreator). It asked for lots of .dll files and I downloaded them one by one,and added to debug folder.
Now I got the error:

```
The program can't start because libwinpthread-1.dll is missing from your computer.
Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.
```

I can't find libwinpthread-1.dll anywhere on the internet. What did I do wrong?

The path to the executable is:

```
C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\build-SimpleText1_3-Desktop_Qt_5_2_1_MinGW_32bit\Debug
```

The project file:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2014-04-04T14:29:48
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = SimpleText1_3
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
CONFIG += console c++11
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
```

And main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Please give concrete paths, main.cpp and project file. Also, re-read the tagwiki. It is Qt, not QT. Are you mixing 32 and 64 bit?

Comment: I don't think I understand your question fully. I use Qt creator x64. When I was downloading dll files, I had to download 32bit dll files (64bit dll's produced more errors in execution).

Comment: Right, so it is likely you mix them. QtCreator can be 32 as well as 64 bit, but you cannot mix the binary with 32 bit and 64 bit dlls and build. Your executable built is 32 bit, and all the dlls, too, right?

Comment: I don't know how can I check my executable built, if it is 32 or 64 bit. But all the dll files I downloaded were 32 bit.

Comment: Can you show some of the dll file names? As for whether the binary is 32 or 64 bit, show the qmake line run, or your spec configuration. It is possible that you are trying to build 64 bit binary.

Comment: icudt51.dll icuin51.dll icuuc51.dll Qt5Gui.dll Qt5Widgets.dll libwinpthread-1.dll and few other. I fixed the problem by building a release instead of debug,and after that I searched Qt directory for each dll requested in errors, until there were no more dll files missing.

Now the application runs, but there is a command prompt shown behind the application. Is it possible to hide that command prompt (console)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run your application in Qt Creator every thing is good but when you run your .exe file fro debug folder you get dll missing error. It`s True!
First set Qt Creator to Release mode. You must copy these dll & the folder to Release folder:

```
platforms --> Folder
icudt52.dll
icuin52.dll
icuuc52.dll
msvcp110.dll
msvcr110.dll
Qt5Core.dll
Qt5Gui.dll
Qt5Widgets.dll
```

Above dll are for Visual Studio compiler & only Core & GUI library.

Good Luck.
Ya Ali.

Comment: How to set the Qt Creator to release mode?

Comment: I set Qt to build to release mode, but the release folder (one next to debug), is empty even after I build the file in release mode. 
Where can i find those files you mentioned in your answer.

Comment: I managed to run it somehow. All of the dll files were already somewhere inside Qt directory,and after I copied them all into the release folder,it worked.

Comment: Glad to hear! Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the following Qt documentation link:
https://wiki.qt.io/Deploy_an_Application_on_Windows.
Follow the instructions precisely.  I did not have to do the brut force approach.  I did get a missing environment variable warning, but the bunding did work.
Be careful about release vs debug builds.